# Android Fragment replace in Tab navigation

Tags: android

In my android application I have one activity that contains two tabs and dynamically loads two Fragments inside the activity.

http://pastebin.com/EP6BFuPw

My problem is this: once I click in a list view inside second fragment, the detail view will show inside this fragment. But when I select the other tab, the first fragment will show (and the second is unchanged, with the detail view inside).

http://pastebin.com/Bnns0uXQ

Comment: seems to me you need to use something known as a FragmentTransaction at : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html and Fragment Manager at : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into this same issue.  I'm using Google's supplied TabListener code and I know where the problem is occurring.  In onTabSelected, we attach the fragment assigned to the stack, and in onTabUnselected we detach the old fragment.  The problem is that once we do a ft.replace() in the list navigation, the TabListener fails to detach the tabs fragment because it is no longer there and has been replaced.

I've tried replacing the fragment in onTabSelected, but then we lose our back stack tracking in the tabs.  My current solution is, instead of using fragment navigation in the tabs, opening a new Activity with the fragment.  If I come up with a better solution to support navigation inside tabs I will let you know.